# Contracting with kronecker delta in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to do some tensor calculations in sympy, but I can't seem to get it to simplify any contractions of tensors against the kronecker delta, i.e. with the minimal example:

```
from sympy import *

n = Idx('n')
i = Idx('i',(1,n))
j = Idx('j',(1,n))

x = IndexedBase('x')
print(Sum(KroneckerDelta(i,j)*x[j],(j,1,n)))
```

here, n is the dimension of the space, and i,j, are indices that run from 1 to n. You would expect the sum to evaluate to x[i], except sympy doesn't do any simplification whatsoever, despite hitting it with the simplify command

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution to your question while I posted a similar question

What you want is the `sympy.concrete.delta.deltasummation` in place of `Sum`

```
print(sympy.concrete.delta.deltasummation(KroneckerDelta(i,j)*x[j],(j,1,n)))
>>> Piecewise((x[i], (n >= i) & (i >= 1)), (0, True))
```

This simplifies further if the KronckerDelta function specifies bounds

```
print(sympy.concrete.delta.deltasummation(KroneckerDelta(i,j,(1,n))*x[j],(j,1,n)))
>>> x[i]
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to automatically replace the Sum with the deltasummation, but at least this is a starting point for you.

There are a few other simplifications to be found in `sympy.concrete` and `sympy.concrete.delta`

edit: link to my somewhat related question [Sympy simplify sum of Kronecker delta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71188296/sympy-simplify-sum-of-kronecker-delta)